# C# - Sorting Strings

Tags: c#, string, sorting, richtextbox

I have a `RichTextBox` that looks similar to this:

```
TEXT  TEXT-1     227.905  174.994  180  1111
TEXT  DIFTEXT    227.905  203.244  180  9999
TEXT  DIFTEXT2   242.210  181.294  180  2222
TEXT  TEXT-2     236.135  198.644  90   ABC1111
TEXT  SOMETEXT   250.610  201.594  0    DDDD
TEXT  OTHERTEXT  269.665  179.894  180  4444
TEXT  OTHERTEXT  269.665  198.144  180  1111
```

And I would like to sort it in a special order. Let's say I want to sort it by the last value *(column 6)* in this sequence:

**1111, 2222, 4444, 9999, DDDD**

AND then sort it *secondly* by the ***2nd column*** alphabetically.

So the updated file would look like this ***NOTE: Since there is no sorting for "ABC1111" it matches the 1111 instead***:

```
TEXT  OTHERTEXT  269.665  179.894  180  1111
TEXT  TEXT-1     227.905  174.994  180  1111
TEXT  TEXT-2     236.135  198.644  90   ABC1111   #See note above
TEXT  DIFTEXT2   242.210  181.294  180  2222
TEXT  OTHERTEXT  269.665  198.144  180  4444
TEXT  DIFTEXT    227.905  203.244  180  9999
TEXT  SOMETEXT   250.610  201.594  0    DDDD
```

And once it is in this format I would like to write it back to the `RichTextBox`.

- How can I do this?

Comment: How is this text being formed in the first place? If it's just given to you like this, OK. But if you are forming it yourself, it would be better to sort it using objects that are aware of the fields in question. In other words, sort this data before it gets dumped out as a string.

Comment: Are the columns fixed width? Will the columns always be separated by one or more spaces? Will columns ever contain spaces? Do you want to sort column six in ASCII order (e.g. 1,10,11,12... 2,3, etc) or numerical order (1,2,3.... 9,10,11)? Do values with less than 4 significant digits have leading zeros? Are all non numeric characters in column six ignored? If so, why is the line featuring DDDD appearing where it is? I think a little more detail is needed here, as there is a lot of ambiguity!

Comment: @Matt Greer: It is given to me like this unfortunately. That is why I am not sure what to do with it. :(

Comment: @Bryan: The columns are not fixed width. The columns are seperated by more than one space. The columns should not contain spaces. Column 6 should be sorted by the given requirements above. However, column 2 should be sorted by numerical/alphabetical order. No there does not need to be leading zeros for digits less than 4 significant digits. No, they are not ignored-- The line that contains `ABC1111` needs to be searched and checked to see if there is any value in it. If it finds the value (in this case "1111") it reads it as that. Any more questions? :)

Comment: What do you mean by "there is no sorting for 'ABC1111'"? Are all leading alpha characters irrelevant? Why is `DDDD` sorted between 2222 and 4444?

Comment: @David Yaw: I mean there is no sorting for ABC1111, however there is sorting for 1111 so it reads it as a '1111'. So in other words, I guess you can say that the leading alpha characters are irrelevant. `DDDD` is sorted between `2222` and `4444` because I am wondering if that is possible. If it is not easily obtainable, sorting numerically and then alphabetically would suffice...

Comment: @theNoobGuy, so are the non numeric characters in column six ignored or not? You told me they aren't, but told David they are? I still don't have a clue why you think DDDD belongs where it is!

Comment: @Bryan: Sorry haha. They are irrelevant meaning they don't matter. However, the `1111` part of the `ABC1111` is relevant. If that makes sense. And lets say that the `DDDD` can be sorted after the numeric values...

Comment: @Bryan: Yes you are correct. :) your post disappeared!

Comment: Yeah, sorry, your previous comment had me all confused again, so I retracted it. It might be worth updating your question to reflect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TextBox class will already give you an array of lines without any work on your part.  Array.Sort will allow you to pass in your own code that compares the lines.  I can't think of an elegant way to implement awkward sorting rules but the way I'd solve your problem would look something like the code below.  Note that you do need to pull out the lines array into a temp variable so you can set it back, otherwise the setter isn't called and the textbox isn't updated.

```
private static void SortRichTextBox(RichTextBox richTextBox)
{
    var lineArray = richTextBox.Lines;
    Array.Sort(lineArray, delegate(string a, string b)
    {
        // I omitted Important corner cases like malformed lines,
        // empty strings, and nulls.

        // Additional sort cases can be added to the array as needed.
        var sortOrder = new[] { "1111", "2222", "4444", "9999", "DDDD" };
        var aTokens = a.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        var bTokens = b.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        var aSignifier = Array.FindIndex(sortOrder, item => aTokens[5].Contains(item));
        var bSignifier = Array.FindIndex(sortOrder, item => bTokens[5].Contains(item));

        // This is where your first rule is being implemented, based on the data
        // from the last column.  The math is unimportant, what matters is the 
        // return being positive vs. negative vs. zero.
        if (aSignifier != bSignifier)
            return aSignifier - bSignifier;

        // This is where your second rule is being implemented, as a backup when
        // the result from the first rule indicates equality.  We're just falling
        // through to ordinary string comparison on the second column.
        return aTokens[1].CompareTo(bTokens[1]);
    });

    // We want to call the setter to get the textbox to update.
    richTextBox.Lines = lineArray;
}
```

I tested this, and it looks like it works, at least with your one sample data set.

Comment: If I have more cases that need to be sorted: say `3333`, `5555`, `6666`, `7777`.. etc.. would I just create more **`if`** statements and placing them in the correct order with correct `return` value?

Comment: Also there is an error about the Index being out of range on the line `var bSignifier = GetSignifier(bTokens[5]);`

Comment: Well, are there only a few cases to be sorted? Cause that's how I read your question originally.  If it is a general rule, then I'd write it a little differently.  What's the general rule?  Sort by number if there is one, and sort by letter if there is no number?

Comment: And, yes, you'll get an out of range error if there is anything unexpected like an empty line at the end of the text.  As the comment says, I left a lot of error checking out.

Comment: Well actually I have a must greater scaled sorting situation.. Here is the order I am trying to get things in: **`RES, 0402, 0201, 0603, 0805, 1206, 1306, 1608, 3216, 2551, 1913, 1313, 2513, 5125, 2525, 5619, 3813, 1508, 6431, 2512, 1505, 2208, 1005, 1010, 2010, 0505, 0705, 1020, 1812, 2225, 5764, 4532, 1210, 0816, 0363, SOT`**

Comment: I have edited the code to make adding sort cases easier.  I stress again that I have left out all the extra handling for things like blank lines.  It should work for your full sort case if you change the appropriate line to: `var sortOrder = new[] { "RES", "0402", "0201", "0603", "0805", "1206", "1306", "1608", "3216", "2551", "1913", "1313", "2513", "5125", "2525", "5619", "3813", "1508", "6431", "2512", "1505", "2208", "1005", "1010", "2010", "0505", "0705", "1020", "1812", "2225", "5764", "4532", "1210", "0816", "0363", "SOT" };`

Comment: Awesome thanks a bunch for your help! I just removed any 'blank' lines so there wont be an error. :). It works like a charm! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string input =
        "TEXT  TEXT-1     227.905  174.994  180  1111\n" +
        "TEXT  DIFTEXT    227.905  203.244  180  9999\n" +
        "TEXT  DIFTEXT2   242.210  181.294  180  2222\n" +
        "TEXT  TEXT-2     236.135  198.644  90   ABC1111\n" +
        "TEXT  SOMETEXT   250.610  201.594  0    DDDD\n" +
        "TEXT  OTHERTEXT  269.665  179.894  180  4444\n" +
        "TEXT  OTHERTEXT  269.665  198.144  180  1111";

    string[] lines = input.Split('\n');
    string[][] grid = new string[lines.Length][];
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
    {
        grid[i] = lines[i].Split((char[])null, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); // split on whitespace
    }

    IEnumerable<string[]> results = grid
        .OrderBy(gridRow => TransformColumn6(gridRow[5]))
        .ThenBy(gridRow => gridRow[1]);

    foreach (string[] gridRow in results)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", gridRow));
    }
}

private static string TransformColumn6(string input)
{
    if (char.IsDigit(input[0]))
    {
        // string is a bunch of numbers, use as-is.
        return input;
    }

    int digitIndex = input.IndexOfAny(new char[] { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' });
    if (digitIndex == -1)
    {
        // string has no numbers, use as-is, will be sorted in alphabetical order after all the numbers.
        return input;
    }

    // string has a number, remove the stuff at the beginning.
    return input.Substring(digitIndex);
}
```

Results (column formatting added manually):

```
TEXT OTHERTEXT 269.665 198.144 180 1111 
TEXT TEXT-1    227.905 174.994 180 1111 
TEXT TEXT-2    236.135 198.644 90  ABC1111 
TEXT DIFTEXT2  242.210 181.294 180 2222 
TEXT OTHERTEXT 269.665 179.894 180 4444 
TEXT DIFTEXT   227.905 203.244 180 9999 
TEXT SOMETEXT  250.610 201.594 0   DDDD
```

If the rules for sorting the last column got much more complicated, then you'd probably want to implement a custom Comparator, instead of using the default string comparison.

Answer (score 0):

I would copy the data to a DataTable and use it to sort by multiple columns and then copy the data back.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.sort.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Bearing in mind the ambiguities highlighted in my comment. You could parse the string into an array of objects (`String.Split` or `String.Substring` may help you here, depending on the structure of your data).

Then use `Array.Sort` (first by the property representing column 2, then by column 6) to sort your array, as per the example [here](http://www.csharp-examples.net/sort-array/) which sorts an array of a custom type.

Create a `.ToString` method for your class to convert each object back into the correct format.

Comment: Ok, I am using `string[] sortedOneRichTextBox = OneRichTextBox.Text.Split('\n');`

Comment: That will split your text into individual objects, but I was thinking more of splitting the individual properties of each object. i.e. `myObject.Field1 = myString.SubString(0,6).Trim(); myObject.Field2 = myString.SubString(6,11).Trim();` etc.

Comment: I am unfamiliar wiht SubString. Do you have a more specific example you could maybe show me? Also, if I split the text using `String.Split` could I sort them by the sortedOneRichTextBox[5] value? and then by the sortedOneRichTextBox[1] value? If so, how could I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Going off your previous question, if you convert them to objects you can use linq to order them.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383982.aspx

Assuming you can get them into objects, you can use 
from  in 
order by , 
select

To get around the abc1111 issue, I would create a separate property that you're sorting on that only contains the 1111.

Also, please remember to accept answers.